# Search engine in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am building a search engine in vb.net which would have to search for a word entered by the user in 40 text files within the project directory.

It should return the results as the total number of matches (text files) and the number of times this word is in each file. Any suggestions for a start would be grateful.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

get a list of the files in the directory with something like: `Directory.GetFiles(ProjectDir, "*.*")`, then read each file in the list like this:

```
        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileName)
        Dim line As String
        Do
            line = sr.ReadLine()
            scan the line and count
        Loop Until line Is Nothing
        sr.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, in a console application, not only could find a word
even you can get the results using a RegEx Expression.

```
Class TextFileInfo
 Public File As System.IO.FileInfo
 public Count As Integer
 public FileText As String
 public ItMatch as Boolean = False

 Sub New (FileFullName as String,WordPattern as String)
      File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileFullName)

      Using Fs As System.IO.StreamReader(File.FullName)
          FileText = Fs.ReadToEnd()'//===>Read Text       
      End Using
      Count = _CountWords(WordPattern,FileText)
      ItMatch = Count > 0
 End Sub

 Public Sub DisplayInfo()
   System.Console.WriteLine("File Name:" + File.Name)
   System.Console.WriteLine("Matched Times:" & Count)   
 End Sub

 Private Function _CountWords(Word As String,Text As String) as  Integer
     Dim RegEx as System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(Word)
    return RegEx.Matches(Text).Count'//===>Returns how many times this word match in the Text
 End Fuction
End Class

Public Function SearchEngine(PatternWord As String,RootDirectory As String) List(Of TextFileInfo)
    Dim MatchedFiles As New List(Of TextFileInfo)
    Dim RootDir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(RootDirectory)

    For Each iTextFile as System.IO.FileInfo In RootDir.GetFiles("*.txt")
            '//===>Create a object of TextFileInfo and check if the file contains the word
             Dim iMatchFile as New TextFileInfo(iTextFiles.FullName,PatternWord)

             If iMatchFile.ItMatch Then
               '//===>Add the object to the list if it has been matches
               MatchedFiles.Add(iMatchFile)
             End If
    Loop

    retur MatchedFiles '//===>Return the results of the files that has the matched word
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim SearchResults as List(Of TextFileInfo) = SearchEngine("JajajaWord","C:\TextFiles\")

        For Each iSearch As TextFileInfo In SearchResults
        iSearch.DisplayInfo()
        Loop

End Sub
```